# How to install something on Ubuntu core?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, installation, serial-port, core

I have an arm-based computer(http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M1) that has it's ported Ubuntu core (http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded). But I man newbie and don't know how can I work with? It has no terminal or other options to do and only shows a Qt program demo. I search many and think I can install something with SSH protocol or connecting my board with Serial to a computer to working with.

But I  don't know more about them! please help me if you know how can I install something on Ubuntu core when I have no terminal on it? :(

Comment: You didn't tell - what hardware are you using ?

Comment: From the link you provided, it looks very much like you can get a terminal by connecting the serial port to your computer (The first thing it advises you on is modifying WIFI  - which it says you do by using a serial terminal, and then proceeds to use standard linux commands.  As its ubuntu based, you can probably install additional software - like SSH, using apt-get install SOFTWARE_PACKAGE  (try apt-cache search keyword to find software)

Comment: @Alex: I have edited the post

Comment: If it is NanoPI, then just plug it to a router, then scan network (with [angryip scanner](http://angryip.org)) to  find its IP and `ssh root@ip.ip.ip.ip`. password AFAIK might be `fa`

Comment: @davidgo: I have only this USB-to_ttl module that I bout it few years ago and didn't work with since now, can I use this for serial connection?  http://opload.ir/im/10m95/491c3663e34f1.jpg
My board also has 4pin for ttl serial connection as it says in it's wiki page.

But I don't know how can I do it?
If there is no difference and it's simpler, can I use ethernet port to do it?(SSH method I think)

Comment: @Alex: I have ADSL=wifi modem. Should I connect my board to my modem Lan ports? or connect it with LAN cable to my laptop?

I have no other options

Comment: SSH to compare with serial port is much more convenient IMHO, but if you prefer serial you need to be make sure that it has 3.3v signal level

Comment: Plug it to you LAN port on router and use AngryIp scanner to find NanoPI's IP

Comment: @Alex: I connected my board with LAN cable directly to my ADSL mode's LAN port, and my laptop is connected with wi-fi to my ADSL modem too. After scanning found 3 host alive that I know one of them is my laptop(dhccpc5), and two others without name.
http://opload.ir/im/10m95/704b5f810ee41.png

Comment: Try to `ssh` to both of them, one should reply

Comment: @Alex: Sorry but how should I try? It's my first time

Comment: Download [putty](http://www.putty.org/) terminal - it is SSH client

Comment: @Alex: You are best man! you solved my problem after one week searching, reading and asking! Thank you very much. I will try it and ask if i have new questions. 

I think you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Can you suggest another option for Linux? I use debian in my laptop.

Comment: Glad we did it :) As about Linux distro for laptop, try LinuxMint (I prefer lightweight XFCE edition), it debian based but more polished. BTW, if you running debian, then you don't need putty, just use `ssh` from terminal as `ssh root@ip.ip.ip.ip`. I will move important comments to the answer, so may be somebody will find it helpful too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your `NanoPI` board to your local network (plug Ethernet port of NanoPI to the LAN port on your router), wait at least a minute to get time `NanoPi` to start then use [AngryIP scanner](http://angryip.org/) to find IP address of `NanoPI`. If you use unix based operation system, use terminal/console to connect to your NanoPI by issue following command:

```
ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Where xx.xx.xx.xx is IP address you found with [AngryIP scanner](http://angryip.org/).

Default password  for *Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded* might be `fa` (check documentation regarding `ssh` password it could be changed since I tried it last time)

If computer you trying to connect from is Windows based operation system, you may use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) terminal as SSH client.